# How can I include <bits/stdc++> in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I have tried to include the header file bits/stdc++ in my C++ code, but it seems the compiler doesn't support it. Is there any way to make it work?

I use OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 and Xcode 6.1.1.

Comment: You aren't supposed to include this header directly. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: I used to include it instead of including many other libraries and save myself a time

Comment: @Omar Except you´ll probably get notably increased compile time. Use the standard headers necessary for your used functions/classes, and not some internal G++ file

Comment: @Omar _"I used to include it instead of ..."_ That's wrong. The headers appearing in the `bits` directory are meant to bind the c++ compiler implementation with your actual machine and OS environment. These are usually included by the higher level implementations of the c++ standard library headers, sometimes only under certain conditions (`#ifdef`'s)

Comment: this library suits my work environment because i need speed in writing, and the high level implementation won't cause any harm

Comment: the thing is, i used to include it on windows, i need a way to make it work on mac

Comment: just copy the file to your working directory and include it...

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: tl;dr your requirement/need is wrong and this is why. No.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I don't see how that's a duplicate. Whether one should, or should not, include a header is different from *how* to include that header.

Comment: I'd be tempted to close this, because the answer to this is a clear "Don't!". The question is based on a flawed assumption and the only accepted answer is an atrocity (yes, my opinion) that discourages understanding of the issue. I'm therefore convinced that SO is better off without this Q than with it.

Comment: The speed in writing argument is fallacious unless you use the header they way it was intended: to facilitate pre-compiled headers. If you include it without taking the proper steps, your build times increase  dramatically, often taking an order of magnitude longer, and quickly eat up the time you saved by not typing the individual headers the program requires.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do it by copying stdc++.h file from here:
https://gist.github.com/reza-ryte-club/97c39f35dab0c45a5d924dd9e50c445f

Then you can include the file in your c++ file like this:

```
 //suppose the file is in your home folder, here my username is reza
 #include "./stdc++.h"
```

Comment: This is a bad advice, hash including the full path is an atrocious act

Comment: Always closely inspect anything you download from the Internet (or get from any other untrustworthy source) before using it.

Answer (score 31):

Since, bits/stdc++ is a GNU GCC extension, whereas OSX uses the clang compiler.

You have to create **bits** directory inside /usr/local/include and then make a header file **stdc++.h** inside bits and paste the contents of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sachin-kmr/ee03a0d07be6fcfd439b49307a12f7ed) inside it.
Then, it should compile as expected.

---

Since, /usr directory is hidden by default on Mac OSX.

1. Open Finder.
2. Click **Go** on menu bar then click **Go to folder** or Press Command+Shift+G directly.
3. Enter the path /usr/local/include
4. Now proceed as mentioned above.

(UPDATE: For latest OS X you need to make folder **include** inside local and make **bits** folder inside **include** folder and then copy paste the code inside **bits** folder.)

Comment: with the above path , not working for me. But with this path it is working
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/"

Comment: for me I had to run "xcode-select -p" first to verify the where was the command line tools folder (it was /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools). And then I found the other folders /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include

Answer (score 22):

Mac OS X 10.9+ no longer uses GCC/libstdc++ but uses libc++ and Clang.

After the XCode 6.0.1 update the headers are now located here:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1`

so, get the stdc++.h file from [here](https://gist.github.com/frankchen0130/9ac562b55fa7e03689bca30d0e52b0e5),then creat **bits** directory in the above long address, and copy the file **stdc++.h** to the **bits** directory.

Comment: At the _very_ least, don't call it "bits/stdc++.h". That's the name of an implementation header in libstdc++. Call it "myHeaderWithAllOfTheStdlib" or something

Comment: Doesn't work. Path is wrong. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 13):

You can't. X-Code uses LLVM Toolchain with Clang for the compiler, while `<bits/stdc++>` is specific to the GNU Compiler Toolchain.

Second, you shouldn't be using that header  in the first place, as stated by everyone else.

Comment: But by creating a folder in "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/" named bits, i can add the stdc++.h and it worked

Answer (score 7):

Before Adding the bits/stdc++.h to your mac os platform, the First things are to figure out where your include files are present. To figure out which include file is getting utilized within you mac environment.

- Run this command in terminal:

  echo "" | gcc -xc - -v -E

This will provide the details of gcc environment in your platform

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
"/Library/Developer/......."
ignoring nonexistent directory 
"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory 
"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include


/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 361 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>" 2
```

- Go to the include path. ex:  /usr/local/include
  Create a bits folder and add [stdc++.h](https://gist.github.com/sachin-kmr/ee03a0d07be6fcfd439b49307a12f7ed) file.

Comment: Thank you. This clearly helped. It's much needed for competitive programming to just import <bits/stdc++.h>

Comment: Maybe, but everywhere else it just gets you into trouble. Don't use `<bits/stdc++.h>` in real code.

Answer (score 3):

In case none of the above solutions work for you.

Try creating a folder named `bits` in

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

[ You can definitely use terminal but if you want to use finder press cmd + shift + G keys (⌘ + ⇧ + G) to goto path menu and paste the above path ]

and create a file named `stdc++.h` and paste the code for stdc++.h file given [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-11/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h)

Comment: This change will likely be lost each time you upgrade Xcode.

Comment: That's true @HangarRash. But I think those upgrades are not very frequent for everyone given the size of Xcode updates.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a header file like bitsStdcpp.hpp file in your file directory,
add the following code in that file
and use #include "bitsStdcpp.hpp" instead of #include <bits/stdc++.h>

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


#ifndef _GLIBCXX_NO_ASSERT
  #include <cassert>
  #endif
  #include <cctype>
  #include <cerrno>
  #include <cfloat>
  #include <ciso646>
  #include <climits>
  #include <clocale>
  #include <cmath>
  #include <csetjmp>
  #include <csignal>
  #include <cstdarg>
  #include <cstddef>
  #include <cstdio>
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <cstring>
  #include <ctime>

  #if __cplusplus >= 201103L
  #include <ccomplex>
  #include <cfenv>
  #include <cinttypes>
  #include <cstdbool>
  #include <cstdint>
  #include <ctgmath>
  #include <cwchar>
  #include <cwctype>
  #endif

  // C++
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <bitset>
  #include <complex>
  #include <deque>
  #include <exception>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <functional>
  #include <iomanip>
  #include <ios>
  #include <iosfwd>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <istream>
  #include <iterator>
  #include <limits>
  #include <list>
  #include <locale>
  #include <map>
  #include <memory>
  #include <new>
  #include <numeric>
  #include <ostream>
  #include <queue>
  #include <set>
  #include <sstream>
  #include <stack>
  #include <stdexcept>
  #include <streambuf>
  #include <string>
  #include <typeinfo>
  #include <utility>
  #include <valarray>
  #include <vector>

  #if __cplusplus >= 201103L
  #include <array>
  #include <atomic>
  #include <chrono>
  #include <condition_variable>
  #include <forward_list>
  #include <future>
  #include <initializer_list>
  #include <mutex>
  #include <random>
  #include <ratio>
  #include <regex>
  #include <scoped_allocator>
  #include <system_error>
  #include <thread>
  #include <tuple>
  #include <typeindex>
  #include <type_traits>
  #include <unordered_map>
  #include <unordered_set>
  

#endif /* bitsStdcpp_hpp */
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that as stated by others also is because Mac OS X 10.9+ no longer uses GCC/libstdc++ but uses libc++ and Clang.

So one alternative way to fix that is to make your default mac compiler from `clang` to `gcc`.

As you can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFyHV.png), the default mac compiler is `clang`.

So, what we can do here is install `gcc`!

#### Step 1

Run the following command to install gcc (assuming [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) is installed on your machine):

```sh
$ brew install gcc
```

#### Step 2

After gcc is installed note the version by running the following command

```sh
$ gcc --version
```

#### Step 3

So now when we run g++-version it will use the gcc compiler, but we want it to use gcc compiler when we run g++. For that we are going to create a symbolic link of g++ to gcc:

```sh
$ cd /usr/local/bin
```

Now create a symbolic link by running this command:

```sh
$ ln -s g++-[version] g++
```

(Replace version by your current installed.)

Now restart the terminal for the changes to take effect and run g++ , it will use gcc compiler. [It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcVk3.png).

Answer (score 0):

for new mac M1 users, just go to applications, in xcode right click and go to Show Package contents,

/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/

in MacOSX10.14.sdk select the one with folder don't click on alias, make a folder bits and a file stdc++.h in it. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

set up vs code for C++ mac and use #include <bits/stdc++.h> in mac like windows

1. install homebrew
2. brew install gcc
3. then create folder in /usr/local/include location
4. create a file name stdc++.h and then paste the below code between *******

---

```
// C++ includes used for precompiling -*- C++ -*-
// Copyright (C) 2003-2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
//
// This file is part of the GNU ISO C++ Library.  This library is free
// software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
// terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
// Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
// any later version.

// This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.

// Under Section 7 of GPL version 3, you are granted additional
// permissions described in the GCC Runtime Library Exception, version
// 3.1, as published by the Free Software Foundation.

// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License and
// a copy of the GCC Runtime Library Exception along with this program;
// see the files COPYING3 and COPYING.RUNTIME respectively.  If not, see
// <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/** @file stdc++.h
 *  This is an implementation file for a precompiled header.
 */

// 17.4.1.2 Headers

// // C
// #ifndef _GLIBCXX_NO_ASSERT
// #include <cassert>
// #endif
// #include <cctype>
// #include <cerrno>
// #include <cfloat>
// #include <ciso646>
// #include <climits>
// #include <clocale>
// #include <cmath>
// #include <csetjmp>
// #include <csignal>
// #include <cstdarg>
// #include <cstddef>
// #include <cstdio>
// #include <cstdlib>
// #include <cstring>
// #include <ctime>

// #if __cplusplus >= 201103L
// #include <ccomplex>
// #include <cfenv>
// #include <cinttypes>
// #include <cstdalign>
// #include <cstdbool>
// #include <cstdint>
// #include <ctgmath>
// #include <cwchar>
// #include <cwctype>
// #endif

// // C++
// #include <algorithm>
// #include <bitset>
// #include <complex>
// #include <deque>
// #include <exception>
// #include <fstream>
// #include <functional>
// #include <iomanip>
// #include <ios>
// #include <iosfwd>
// #include <iostream>
// #include <istream>
// #include <iterator>
// #include <limits>
// #include <list>
// #include <locale>
// #include <map>
// #include <memory>
// #include <new>
// #include <numeric>
// #include <ostream>
// #include <queue>
// #include <set>
// #include <sstream>
// #include <stack>
// #include <stdexcept>
// #include <streambuf>
// #include <string>
// #include <typeinfo>
// #include <utility>
// #include <valarray>
// #include <vector>
// #include <unordered_map>
// #include <unordered_set>

// #if __cplusplus >= 201103L
// #include <array>
// #include <atomic>
// #include <chrono>
// #include <condition_variable>
// #include <forward_list>
// #include <future>
// #include <initializer_list>
// #include <mutex>
// #include <random>
// #include <ratio>
// #include <regex>
// #include <scoped_allocator>
// #include <system_error>
// #include <thread>
// #include <tuple>
// #include <typeindex>
// #include <type_traits>

// #endif

// C
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_NO_ASSERT
#include <cassert>
#endif
#include <cctype>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cfloat>
#include <ciso646>
#include <climits>
#include <clocale>
#include <cmath>
#include <csetjmp>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#include <ccomplex>
#include <cfenv>
#include <cinttypes>
//#include <cstdalign>
#include <cstdbool>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctgmath>
#include <cwchar>
#include <cwctype>
#endif

// C++
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <complex>
#include <deque>
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <list>
#include <locale>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <new>
#include <numeric>
#include <ostream>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#include <array>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <forward_list>
#include <future>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <mutex>
#include <random>
#include <ratio>
#include <regex>
#include <scoped_allocator>
#include <system_error>
#include <thread>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeindex>
#include <type_traits>

#endif
```

then follow these instructions :

Open User-Level Settings in VS Code:

1.press  cmd + shift + p .
2. Type and select "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" from the command palette. This will open the settings.json file for your user-level settings. or somehow open settings.json file in vs code.
3. add or modify these two lines in code

```
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
     "/usr/local/include" // Add global include paths here
 ],
"C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++" // Set the default compiler path
```

4. Ensure that you have the correct "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath" pointing to your GCC/G++ compiler and "C_Cpp.default.includePath" set to include the global include paths you want.
5. Save the Settings File:
6. Restart Visual Studio Code:

done..you can run cpp file

now bonus part. just download a new extension called Competitive Coding Helper (cph). then go to  settings and search cph . then in Cph>Language > Cpp:Args section add -std=c++17. you can use this extention. it's best extention for c++. done

Answer (score -1):

The standard GNU compiler, G++ Does not directly support this header so we include it in the required location using the following steps :

1. cd /usr/local/include
2. mkdir bits
3. nano stdc++.h

then copy the code of the header file from [here](https://github.com/seepls/Javaaa/blob/master/stdc%2B%2B.h) .

Hope that helps ! :D

Comment: GCC does support it. The problem is that MacOS has `g++` symlinked to Clang.

Answer (score -1):

After creating a `symbolic link` to g++ at `/usr/local/bin/` it should work.

**Command for symbolic link:-**

`sudo ln -s $(which g++-11) /usr/local/bin/g++`

If the `bin` directory is missing, then create the `bin` directory first.

Answer (score -2):

1. Open Finder.
2. Click Go on menu bar then click Go to folder or Press Command+Shift+G directly.
3. Enter the path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1

Now, get the stdc++.h file from [here](https://gist.github.com/eduarc/6022859), then create bits directory in the above long address, and copy the file stdc++.h to the bits directory.

Comment: No, this is monumentally silly. That's a header from Linux GCC 4.8, not Mac Clang <whatever your version is>. **Do not do this** I cannot stress it enough.

Comment: Saved my life, Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7 and Xcode version is Version 12.4 (12D4e)

Answer (score -2):

1.Download the stdc++.h file from https://gist.github.com/eduarc/6....

2.In Finder CTRL + SHIFT +G  and open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/

3.Create the folder bits and copy the downloaded file here.

Answer (score -2):

1. Open Finder.
2. Click Go on menu bar then click Go to folder or Press Command+Shift+G directly.
3. Enter the path or c/p this path directly

> */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1*

4. Then create bits directory in the above long address.
5. Now, get the stdc++.h file from [here][1].
6. and copy the file stdc++.h to the bits directory.

Answer (score -2):

1. Copy the content of this header file to clipboard from Link: https://gist.github.com/reza-ryte-club/97c39f35dab0c45a5d924dd9e50c445f
2. Run following in terminal :

   - mkdir /usr/local/include/bits
   - vim /usr/local/include/bits/stdc++.h
   - Switch to insert mode (press i) and Paste clipboard content
   - Save/Exit (Esc + : + w + q + Enter)
3. Try compliation of your source code

Answer (score -2):

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1`

TRY THIS PATH to create the bits folder and add the stdc++.h file.

Comment: no specific path is important, you can create the header file anywhere

Answer (score -2):

The basic solution is to create the `bits` folder and `stdc++.h` file where the compiler is looking for its libraries.

To find this for g++ or gcc go to the terminal and write

```
**g++ -print-search-dirs**
```

You'll get something like this:

```
programs: =/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
libraries: =/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0
```

Go to the libraries location inside the include folder create a `bits` folder. Inside the `bits` folder create a `stdc++.h` file with these [contents](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-11/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h).

Note if you face some error like a particular header file not found please comment those lines in `stdc++.h`.

Answer (score -2):

**Header files** may contain **Function definitions**, **Data type definitions** and **Macros**

You need to understand that in `bits/stdc++.h`, **bits** is the folder name that's useless to you right now, the header file is **stdc++.h**.

**Step 1:** Create a file named `stdc++.h` with following content.

```
// C++ includes used for precompiling -*- C++ -*-

// Copyright (C) 2003-2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
//
// This file is part of the GNU ISO C++ Library.  This library is free
// software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
// terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
// Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
// any later version.

// This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.

// Under Section 7 of GPL version 3, you are granted additional
// permissions described in the GCC Runtime Library Exception, version
// 3.1, as published by the Free Software Foundation.

// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License and
// a copy of the GCC Runtime Library Exception along with this program;
// see the files COPYING3 and COPYING.RUNTIME respectively.  If not, see
// <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/** @file stdc++.h
 *  This is an implementation file for a precompiled header.
 */

// 17.4.1.2 Headers

// C
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_NO_ASSERT
#include <cassert>
#endif
#include <cctype>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cfloat>
#include <ciso646>
#include <climits>
#include <clocale>
#include <cmath>
#include <csetjmp>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#include <ccomplex>
#include <cfenv>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cstdbool>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctgmath>
#include <cwchar>
#include <cwctype>
#endif

// C++
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <complex>
#include <deque>
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <list>
#include <locale>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <new>
#include <numeric>
#include <ostream>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#include <array>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <forward_list>
#include <future>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <mutex>
#include <random>
#include <ratio>
#include <regex>
#include <scoped_allocator>
#include <system_error>
#include <thread>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeindex>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#endif
```

---

**Step 2:** Add `include "stdc++.h"` on top of your file where you want to include this header file,
Note: *always put path with file name, as if your header file is in `C:/Folder1` then you should write*
`include "C:/Folder1/stdc++.h"`

Comment: if you find any errors while including any header file, that's inside `stdc++.h` header file, simply comment it out from `stdc++.h` file!
Ofcourse if file is not important to you, if it's needed find other alternatives!

Answer (score -2):

If you update to MacOS 12.3, most of the existing answers on the Internet will fail. Open a folder with this:

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

Or you can directly peel off Xcode layer by layer with the graphical interface. You will see two folders, one with an arrow and one without.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAc8s.png)

Obviously, this is caused by the change of folder path caused by MacOS update. Because the contents of the two folders are almost the same ,you can hardly find out the cause. Your Xcode can find the standard header file(like `stdio.h`) in the new path, but can't find the `stdc++.h` you added, because you added it to the old path.

Answer (score -2):

if you are  adding the bits folder in the below path "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/"
and still stuck,to fix it copy the all the c++(and comment out the c headers in stdc++.h file) headers from stdc++.h file and add it in to a simple c
++ code and run it in xcode,see the header which is creating problem and then comment it out in stdc++.h file and it will be fixed

Comment: Please can you edit your answer to be more readable and clear

Answer (score -2):

For latest Xcode version 13.4.x:
Goto this path

1. Applications > Xcode > Contents > Developer > Platforms > MacOSX.platform > Developer > SDKs > MacOSX.sdk > usr > include > c++ > v1

OR

In finder press Cmd + Shift + G

and enter the following address
/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1

2. Create a new folder with the name "bits"
3. paste your stdc++.h file in this folder (you can get the stdc++.h file [here](https://gist.github.com/Einstrasse/ac0fe7d7450621a39364ed3b05cacd11))

In the code, you can simply add the following line to include the stdc++.h file.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
```

Answer (score -4):

I have written a detailed article on Medium explaining how to resolve this issue elegantly. You may read it [here](https://justvikram.medium.com/how-to-include-bits-stdc-h-header-file-with-clang-compiler-on-macos-4ed52a9f80f5).

TLDR:

Download the [linked file](https://dropover.cloud/b831d6). Go to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1` and copy the downloaded file to that directory. You can start using `#include <stdcpp.h>` in your projects instead of manually including all required header files.

Comment: The actual solution and explanation should be part of the stackoverflow answer, not just a reference to an external site. The code in the linked file should also be explained, not just given as is for people to include in their projects without knowledge of what it should do.

Comment: @devil0150 that’s ridiculous. The answer should be short and to the point, and if someone’s really interested then they may choose to  read the article to understand the minute details. What’s there to explain in the code? Its literally just a bunch of #include statements that include every header file imaginable. Do you really expect me to explain the purpose of each and every header file?