# Workspace-specific includePath for Visual Studio Code

Tags: include, visual-studio-code

This question: [Visual Studio Code includePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-includepath) shows how to modify the global includePath for Visual Studio code to change the locations VSCode looks for header files. I want to change the includePath, but just for a single project, not all projects. Is there a way to make changes to the include path that only apply to a single project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The c_cpp_properties.json file described in that question is in the .vscode folder in your workspace, so it is already project specific.

If you use the "Add include path to settings" feature the extension will create a c_cpp_properties.json file with the system default paths, but that is only to help you get started, it does not mean that is a global configuration.