# What are the correct macOS vscode intellisense C++ include paths for the standard library?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.14.2 on macOS Sierra and have installed the Microsoft C/C++ `ms-vscode.cpptools` extension but am having trouble setting up the include paths to get standard library headers to be correctly inspected by IntelliSense without producing errors and falling back to the 'Tag Parser' mechanism.

The default `c_cpp_properties.json` contains the following for this vscode version:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Mac",
      "includePath": [
        "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1",
        "/usr/local/include",
        "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/8.1.0/include",
        "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include",
        "/usr/include",
        "${workspaceRoot}"
      ],
      "defines": [],
      "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
      "browse": {
        "path": [
          "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1",
          "/usr/local/include",
          "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/8.1.0/include",
          "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include",
          "/usr/include",
          "${workspaceRoot}"
        ],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
        "databaseFilename": ""
      }
    },
...
}
```

For example, with a simple C++ file such as:

```
#include <exception>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The `#include <exception>` is underlined. Hovering over it states:

> file: 'file:///path/to/vscode.cc'
>   severity: 'Info'
>   message: '#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit (/path/to/vscode.cc) will be provided by the Tag Parser.'
>   at: '1,1'
>   source: ''

and

> file: 'file:///path/to/vscode.cc'
>   severity: 'Info'
>   message: 'cannot open source file "endian.h" (dependency of "exception")'
>   at: '1,1'
>   source: ''

I did a search of my filesystem for `endian.h`. Trimming out the possibilities that seem actually relevant for host development (i.e. dropping iOS/WatchOS/etc.):

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/i386/endian.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/machine/endian.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/i386/endian.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/endian.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/i386/endian.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/machine/endian.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/i386/endian.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/endian.h
/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/i386/endian.h
/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/machine/endian.h
/usr/include/i386/endian.h
/usr/include/machine/endian.h
```

Does anyone know what the correct fix for this issue is?

Comment: I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-includepath and the comments on it but despite the responses there, I still see the same problem. I tried adding the suggested path to the list of include paths and it did not help.

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be a configuration bug in the IntelliSense engine.  Mac headers expected the symbol `__LITTLE_ENDIAN__` to be defined and it wasn't.  We have corrected this issue in the latest update of the extension, so there is no need to add a path to endian.h anymore.