# VS Code giving header errors for Arduino? Missing official header?

Tags: arduino, visual-studio-code, arduino-uno

I've recently started developing for Arduino. Initially I used the Arduino IDE but I soon realised it was not up to par. Development was considerably slower with the need for IDE restarts every now and then. I found VS Code with the Arduino Extension which I've come to love. However I have a few issues and I'm not sure how to solve it.

First of all vs code throws #include errors and asks me to update IntelliSense. However it builds/uploads and runs perfectly well, it also finds the classes etc. defined in said includes so it looks like it's a false positive in some way (i.e. the path is included in includePath settings). Reading the error message also shows it having issues finding a header referenced in Arduino.h called "avr/pgmspace.h". I'm unsure if these errors are related. pgmspace.h is nowhere to be found (it should have been included in the Arduino SDK).

Finally because of the #include error anything related to that particular header file will not be highlighted properly and is just plain gray text which is a bit annoying.

Anyone knows how to fix this? I'm on a Mac btw.

[image: Error messages]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update**: Extra libraries do not need to be installed. IntelliSense can operate using only the headers installed by the Arduino app, but a few others may help. More updates below.

<s>When VSCode builds, it uses the SDK. However, IntelliSense cannot read the SDK files to operate (as far as I can tell), which throws these annoying errors and eliminates most code completion capabilities.</s>

Both `includePath` and `browse.path` need to be configured. `includePath` does not include recursively (but that feature seems to be coming soon). `browse.path` is recursive, but including the exact location of header files is in `includePath` is still necessary for IntelliSense features. `browse.path` will use the Tag Parser to provide tools such as the "lightbulb" that you can click to help resolve your `includePath` issue. (Source: [What is the difference between "includePath" and "browse.path" in c_cpp_properties.json?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/FAQ.md#what-is-the-difference-between-includepath-and-browsepath-in-c_cpp_propertiesjson))

---

### Mac:

`avr/pgmspace.h` is located at: `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/pgmspace.h`. It's coded into the libraries as `avr/pgmspace.h`; for this reason, we need to include the path that `avr`is located in.

#### 1. <s>Install [homebrew-avr](https://github.com/osx-cross/homebrew-avr):</s>

#### 2. Edit c_cpp_properties.json:

```
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/libraries",
    "/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers",
    "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries",
    "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include",
    "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard"
],
"browse": {
    "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false,
    "path": [
        "/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers",
        "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/"
    ]
},
"forcedInclude": [
    "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Arduino.h"
],
```

---

### Windows 10:

#### 1. <s>Install [WinAVR](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winavr/)</s>

#### 2. Edit c_cpp_properties.json:

Revise `includePath` to look like this:

```
"includePath": [
    "{$workspaceFolder}/libraries",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/include",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino",
],
```

---

#### Alternative Method (probably a bad idea):

If you can get a version of any missing library, you can probably put in in your `libraries` folder of your project if your `includePath` includes `"${workspaceFolder}/libraries"`. Make sure to namespace your libraries appropriately, e.g. `libraries/avr/pgmspace.h`. I have not tested this method.

---

**Updates:**

- <s>Changed from home.path to includePath. See more here: [vscode-cpptools/FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/FAQ.md#what-is-the-difference-between-includepath-and-browsepath-in-c_cpp_propertiesjson)</s>
- The tools downloaded by the `vscode-arduino` libraries are not necessary on Windows 10.
- Changed Windows config paths to use forward slashes instead of escaped backslashes.

---

Source and further tips: [Enabling Arduino Intellisense with Visual Studio Code](http://cuneyt.aliustaoglu.biz/en/enabling-arduino-intellisense-with-visual-studio-code/)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. It seems to be a bug tbh as it doesnt seem to respect the includePaths. I'm going to post a bug on Github and report back if it gets resolved.

Comment: Please share that issue thread here, if you can. I would be interested to know as well.

Comment: So I got it working. Unfortunately I'm not sure exactly what made it work. It was probably a number of things. I'm leaning towards suspecting that there was a clash in multiple intellisense engines working at once. My instance of VS Code had at two Intellisense extensions installed. Now I'm only running the official C/C++ one and it seems to do the trick. I'm gonna mark your answer correct anyway.

Comment: Thanks, and good to know. As I've moved on to working with other libraries, I've repeatedly run into issues that don't make sense. Yesterday, IntelliSense threw errors for a .io  in one project and not the other, and I had copy-pasted the entire c_cpp_properties.json and fixed small details regarding relative file paths. My instantiation of Serial() said it had no declaration, but I could right-click and use Go To/Peek definition that took me to the header. The whole system seems like it needs improvement. I would also appreciate if Arduino.cc had better  documentation about their libraries.

Comment: this file gets regenerated..doesnt keep the paths you manually added for your custom header files

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. Can't find nor create c_cpp_properties.json file. Also, I wanted it to be global, and not only to one project/workspace/folder.

So, for VSCode 1.14 (2019) I just navigate till settings.json (the global one), and add this json section:

```
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/libraries/**",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/**",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/**",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/include/**",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard/**",
    "C:/Users/<YOUR USERNAME>/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoavr/**",
    "C:/Users/<YOUR USERNAME>/Documents/Arduino/libraries/**",
    "{$workspaceFolder}/libraries/**",
    "{$workspaceFolder}/**"
],
"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser"
```

Posted another answer with the entire procedure and all details about the approach: [Visual Studio Code includePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-includepath/58839719#58839719)

Comment: Not sure how you ”can not create” the file. It’s your file system :) but glad you got it working.

Comment: @sebrock I mean that i can't find any option to create that automatically, as other solutions (not in this question) suggests. There is a tutorial that says: "click on the error. That will create the c_cpp_properties.json file for you. I simple could not find that option anywhere, also didn't know where to create that file, nor what format/structure it should be (what properties, values, etc...)

Comment: @sebrock so... sure, i could create a .json file anywhere hehe. But I didn't and still do not have any idea where to create that, and what properties and values it should have. Anyway, my solutions seems lot easier, and gets the job done. : )

Answer (score 2):

I am using VSC for code editor, and need only intellisense. I set in the arduino IDE preferences "use external editor" and I using it for compile and upload.

My win username "bunny" and the Sketchbook location is "C:\person\Arduino"  for understand the folders. I am using latest VSC (1.56.2) and ArduinoIDE (1.8.13)

My settings.json like this, there is working well with all library included special like esp8266 etc:

```
{
"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser",
    "C_Cpp.default.browse.path": [
        "c:/Person/Arduino/libraries",
        "c:/Person/Arduino/hardware",
        "c:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware",
        "c:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/libraries",
        "c:/Users/Bunny/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages",
        "${workspaceFolder}"
    ]
}
```

Comment: None of the other answers seemed to work, but this one did (VSC 1.70.0, Arduino 1.8.13). I only needed to include "${workspaceFolder}", as vs code (IntelliSense) was only confused about include files in my project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52343289/7568866) is very good.
I had to include some other folders as well, my includePath looks like this and I have no IntelliSense erros any more:

```
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/include",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard",
                "C:/Users/<USER_NAME>/Documents/Arduino/libraries/**",
                "C:/Users/<USER_NAME>/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.5/libraries/**",
                "C:/Users/<USER_NAME>/AppData/Local/Arduino15/libraries/**"
            ],
```

You can use these paths as inspiration to add if you encounter some header that cannot be found (like `SPI.h` or `Ethernet.h`).

Comment: it regenerates this file each time you verify/compile.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned `c_cpp_properties.json` is located inside the project's `.vscode` directory.

If not present you can create it in VSCode by pressing *Ctrl+Shift+P* and typing the *C/C++: Edit Configurations (JSON)* command.

To improve upon *Stefan*'s answer you can use `${env:USERNAME}` in replacement of `<USER_NAME>` to make it automatically replaced by the current user's name.

These worked out for me:

```
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/**",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/include",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard",
    "C:/Users/${env:USERNAME}/Documents/Arduino/libraries/**",
    "C:/Users/${env:USERNAME}/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/**",
    "C:/Users/${env:USERNAME}/Documents/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_GFX_Library/",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SPI/src"         
],
```

This was also useful, to change the compiler to gcc as [naigonakoii suggests here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-arduino/issues/678#issuecomment-662230997):

```
"compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc.exe",
"intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x86",
```

And by adding some defines we have the ultimate anti-squiggly-line configuration (You might need to change the last one for the model you're using

```
"defines": [
    "_DEBUG",
    "UNICODE",
    "_UNICODE",
    "ARDUINO=100",
    "USBCON",
    "__AVR_ATmega328P__"
],
```