# How to configure Visual Studio Code includePath for Arduino and Teensy

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, arduino, intellisense, include-path

I'm working with Arduino and Teensy boards from inside VS code. I can build and program everything fine, but the highlighting and code following functions built into VS Code don't work.

Previously, my custom headers weren't loading or highlighting, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234438/vs-code-giving-header-errors-for-arduino-missing-official-header/52343289) got that working for me. Now I have the right libraries on my include path (and I can click and follow them to the correct source) but some names still don't work:

[image]

[image]

My `includePath` appears to be configured correctly, as I mentioned I can follow the includes and it opens the correct sources:

```
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/**",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/teensy/avr/cores/teensy/**",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/teensy/avr/libraries/ADC/**",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/**",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard/**",
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/lib/gcc/avr/5.4.0/include/**"
]
```

I can confirm the header is on the includePath and has the names defined I'm looking for:

[image]

Somehow VS Code is still saying the identifier is undefined.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to have a look at VisualTeensy https://github.com/luni64/VisualTeensy/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide. It generates all required vsCode files for Teensy projects. Even if you don't want to use it, it has a life display of the generated files so you can easily experiment with Teensy settings and watch the effect on generated files.

Comment: How are you adding IncludePaths for compilation/building?

Answer (score 5):

Just install the [Arduino extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.vscode-arduino) and run vscode command `Arduino: initialize`. You will need to select board and

File `.vscode\c_cpp_properties.json` and `.vscode\arduino.json` will automatically created.

Comment: Doing this does not update the include path for the installed Arduino libraries. In my case I have a standalone portable installation and need to get the include path updated to include that location.

Comment: @RyanHiggins This works with normal installation and arduino cli as well.

Comment: This works! I'd add just one more thing, for newbies like me, you have to change the C/C++ Configuration from "Win32" to "Arduino" in the bottom right

Comment: What if I want my own include path to my own libs?

Comment: My c_cpp_properties file wouldn't be updated by the extension until I deleted it and reran the initialize command.

Comment: @E.Morell You can control that behavior with settings key `"intelliSenseGen"` (`"enable"|"disable"|"global"`) per project in `.vscode/arduino.json`. Alternatively, you can set the default for all projects in your global user settings with a slightly different key `"arduino.disableIntelliSenseAutoGen"` (`true|false`)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others: install the [Arduino extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.vscode-arduino) and run
`Arduino: initialize` to generate the `.vscode\arduino.json` file.

Now, `.vscode\c_cpp_properties.json` should also be created, but if it isn't, You can run `Arduino: verify` (or just `Arduino: upload`) to generate/update it.

Also, in my case the extension complained when the main `.ino` file name didn't match the folder name, regardless of the "sketch" field in `arduino.json`.

Comment: Your answer should stand on its own without relying on others. Currently there are three deleted answers to this question; if the one you've mentioned gets deleted, will your answer still make sense? (Of course, if you use information from another answer, you should also properly attribute it.)

Comment: @miken32 right thx, I modified it a bit.