# Unable to get Visual Studio Code to work with Clang on MacOSX for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, llvm

I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac).

Error I am getting is **#include errors detected. Please update your includePath** on the line where I do #include or #include

I found similar StackOverflow issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-includepath) but nothing helped.

I found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1863) Github issue filed and went through it but it didn't help.

I checked that I have clang installed in my Mac. It is present at location `/usr/bin`. 
I have also verified that header files such as algorithm, iostream, stdc++ are present in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0`

How to fix this issue?

Here are my configuration files:

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.1.0/include/c++/7.1.0"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/System/Library/Frameworks",
                "/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build with Clang",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "test.cpp",
                "-o",
                "test.out",
                "--debug"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "(lldb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "lldb",
        "logging": {
          "trace": true,
          "traceResponse": true,
          "engineLogging": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

settings.json:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "valarray": "cpp",
        "ios": "cpp",
        "random": "cpp",
        "__locale": "cpp",
        "__string": "cpp",
        "regex": "cpp",
        "string": "cpp",
        "string_view": "cpp",
        "utility": "cpp",
        "iosfwd": "cpp",
        "chrono": "cpp",
        "complex": "cpp",
        "__bit_reference": "cpp",
        "__hash_table": "cpp",
        "__split_buffer": "cpp",
        "__tree": "cpp",
        "array": "cpp",
        "deque": "cpp",
        "forward_list": "cpp",
        "initializer_list": "cpp",
        "iterator": "cpp",
        "list": "cpp",
        "map": "cpp",
        "set": "cpp",
        "unordered_map": "cpp",
        "unordered_set": "cpp",
        "vector": "cpp",
        "algorithm": "cpp",
        "limits": "cpp",
        "__config": "cpp",
        "__nullptr": "cpp",
        "cstddef": "cpp",
        "exception": "cpp",
        "stdexcept": "cpp",
        "type_traits": "cpp",
        "typeinfo": "cpp",
        "atomic": "cpp",
        "*.tcc": "cpp",
        "bitset": "cpp",
        "cctype": "cpp",
        "cfenv": "cpp",
        "cinttypes": "cpp",
        "clocale": "cpp",
        "cmath": "cpp",
        "codecvt": "cpp",
        "condition_variable": "cpp",
        "csetjmp": "cpp",
        "csignal": "cpp",
        "cstdarg": "cpp",
        "cstdint": "cpp",
        "cstdio": "cpp",
        "cstdlib": "cpp",
        "cstring": "cpp",
        "ctime": "cpp",
        "cuchar": "cpp",
        "cwchar": "cpp",
        "cwctype": "cpp",
        "functional": "cpp",
        "memory": "cpp",
        "memory_resource": "cpp",
        "numeric": "cpp",
        "ratio": "cpp",
        "system_error": "cpp",
        "tuple": "cpp",
        "fstream": "cpp",
        "future": "cpp",
        "iomanip": "cpp",
        "iostream": "cpp",
        "istream": "cpp",
        "mutex": "cpp",
        "new": "cpp",
        "optional": "cpp",
        "ostream": "cpp",
        "scoped_allocator": "cpp",
        "shared_mutex": "cpp",
        "sstream": "cpp",
        "streambuf": "cpp",
        "thread": "cpp",
        "typeindex": "cpp",
        "queue": "cpp",
        "stack": "cpp",
        "__functional_03": "cpp",
        "__debug": "cpp",
        "__errc": "cpp",
        "__functional_base": "cpp",
        "__mutex_base": "cpp",
        "__node_handle": "cpp",
        "__threading_support": "cpp",
        "__tuple": "cpp",
        "any": "cpp",
        "charconv": "cpp",
        "locale": "cpp",
        "span": "cpp",
        "variant": "cpp",
        "filesystem": "cpp"
    }
}
```