# VS Code can't include OpenCV headers

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, visual-studio-code

I got some problem with using OpenCV on VS Code for C++.

I can compile the C code but when I include the OpenCV libraries, it always displays the following error message:

> fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory

My VS Code version is 1.41.1 (user setup).

I downloaded OpenCV 3.4.1 from this site:
https://github.com/huihut/OpenCV-MinGW-Build

The environment path in my computer is:

[image: Text]

The path to OpenCV is D://opencv//build.

Here are my configurations for using OpenCV in VS Code:

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\bin\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "啟用 gdb 的美化顯示",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

task.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-I",
                "D:\\opencv\\build\\include",
                "-L",
                "D:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\mingw\\bin",
                "-l",
                "libopencv_calib3d341",
                "-llibopencv_core341",
                "-llibopencv_dnn341",
                "-llibopencv_features2d341",
                "-llibopencv_flann341",
                "-llibopencv_highgui341",
                "-llibopencv_imgcodecs341",
                "-llibopencv_imgproc341",
                "-llibopencv_ml341",
                "-llibopencv_objdetect341",
                "-llibopencv_photo341",
                "-llibopencv_shape341",
                "-llibopencv_stitching341",
                "-llibopencv_superres341",
                "-llibopencv_video341",
                "-llibopencv_videoio341",
                "-llibopencv_videostab341"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\include",                
                "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\8.1.0\\include",
                "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\8.1.0\\include\\c++",
                "D:\\opencv\\build\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "__GNUC__=5",
                "__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__))"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\include",                    
                    "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\8.1.0\\include",                
                    "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\8.1.0\\include\\c++",                    
                    "D:\\opencv\\build\\include"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code includePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-includepath)

Comment: no i have followed he step that post still can't find the lib

Comment: Is the path set for both release and debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

is "D:\opencv\build\include" your opencv installed path? you can cd to that directory and check if "opencv2/opencv.hpp" exists. The point is to find where "opencv2/opencv.hpp" locates in your system and put that path to the c_cpp_properties.json "includePath".