# How to include a header file when the file that is including it is not in the root project folder?

Tags: c++, include

I am trying to learn how to better organize a project and it's files in C++.

My simple test project only seems to work whenever main.cpp (and main.exe) is in the root project folder. Here's how I wanted to try to set it up.

- Project

  - .vscode

    - c_cpp_properties.json
  - headers

    - header.h
  - main

    - main.cpp
    - main.exe

Inside of main.cpp, I have `#include "headers/header.h"`

When I try to compile it with this setup, I get this error
`fatal error: headers/header.h: No such file or directory`

I am wondering why this doesn't work when the following setup, which doesn't have main.cpp in a subfolder, compiles and runs just fine (without changing any of the code).

- Project

  - .vscode

    - c_cpp_properties.json
  - headers

    - header.h
  - main.cpp
  - main.exe

I am using Visual Studio Code with the C/C++ and C/C++ Compile Run extensions (in case that's relevant).

Edit:

Changing it to `"../headers/header.h"` does work, but I am wondering how I would do this without using `../`.

If I'm understanding correctly I just need to add something to the includePath in c_cpp_properties.json. Here's what the `"includePath"` section looks like right now.

```
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**"
],
```

So I think I just need to make it something like

```
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "..."
],
```

What exactly should I be putting in the `...` part?

Comment: the compiler looks relative to the current file. Use `#include "../headers/header.h"`

Answer (score 0):

When compiling a specific file, your compiler will look at the path of this file. So, in your first example, it is `.../Project/main/main.cpp`, but in your second example it's `../Project/main.cpp`. 
So now its obvious why looking at the path that is `headers/header.h` is valid in second case, but not the first one.

However, you can of course leave your `main.cpp` in your `main` directory if you wish, you'd only need to set `INCLUDE_PATH` directory. If you were using `Makefile`, it'd be a simple `-I` flag addition, but since you're using VS code, you might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-includepath). Sorry I can't provide more detailed solution, I'm not really familiar with VS Code environment.