# Visual Studio Code C/C++ Extension doesn't set the include path for the compiler

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I installed the C/C++ Extension for Visual Studio Code (`ms-vscode.cpptools`) and I'm trying to compile a .cpp file, but I keep getting `fatal error C1034: iostream: no include path set`.

Here is the contents of `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/Fe:",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the contents of `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "8.1",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and here is the exact output:

> **> Executing task: cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /Fe: c:\Users\User\Documents\C\cpp_workshop-cpp_ex2\main.exe
> c:\Users\User\Documents\C\cpp_workshop-cpp_ex2\main.cpp <**
>
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24213.1 for x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> main.cpp
>
> c:\Users\User\Documents\C\cpp_workshop-cpp_ex2\main.cpp(21):
> fatal error C1034: iostream: no include path set
>
> The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Help me, Stack Overflow. You're my only hope!

Comment: Does [Visual Studio Code `includePath`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37548293/7582247) help?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not really. It says [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_compiler-path) that "You only need to add to the Include path array setting if your program includes header files that are not in your workspace or in the standard library path."

Comment: Ok, are you starting VS Code from a Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio? [issue 3654](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3654): "_In case you get the error C1034: iostream: no include path set: If you haven't already, start VS code from the Developer Command Prompt that is installed with the MSVC compiler set. If you have everything resolved now, very good. If not, continue.

In case you get the error fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64', you need to start VS Code from the x64 Developer Command Prompt_"

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, it works now. Thanks! But it's pretty cumbersome, and it only builds one file at a time. I think I'll migrate to CMake.

Comment: Great that it worked! You can probably split the building up in smaller tasks and create a dependency graph in tasks.json too (with linking as the task that `dependsOn` the compilation tasks) - [If you list more than one task in the `dependsOn` property they are executed in parallel.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23160#issuecomment-422309846)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Do you know a way to automatically generate `tasks.json` from all the .cpp files in the open folder?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. No I have actually no experience with Visual Studio Code. I'd expect an option in VSCode to add one or many files to the project though.

Answer (score 4):

I had same Problem which solved as [Ted Lyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582247/ted-lyngmo) says :

*open vscode with developer command prompt.*

Edit : 
When i open vscode with Developer Command Prompt(DCP) it don't gives such an error.
To open DCP follow steps below : 
1- Open start menu(`WIN` key) and start typing "Developer Command Prompt" it should appear there.
2- After opening it write `code .` and run it. This way you opened vs code from DCP.
3- Navigate desired folder *inside* vscode and create cpp files there.
4- After you write your "Helloworld.cpp" press `CTRL + SHIFT + B`, this will compile your code

i hope this helps

Comment: Be more descriptive about the solution.

Answer (score -2):

I thought yağız's instructions were pretty clear and this was the one solution that worked for me but for those who requested more details:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]