# Visual Studio Code IncludePath Issue with ROS headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, ros

I'm getting squiggly lines under the statements of `#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"` from the [ROS2 tutorial](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber/#cpppubsub) I'm going through and updating IncludePath in `c_cpp_properties.json` is not fixing the issue.

Here's what my c_cpp_properties file looks like:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "browse": {
                "databaseFilename": "",
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            },
            "includePath": [
                "/opt/ros/foxy/include/**",
                "/home/thomas/ws_ros2/src/cpp_pubsub/include/**",
                "/usr/include/**"
            ],
            "name": "ROS",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

The ROS extension recognizes that I'm working with a ROS package so my `settings.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "/home/thomas/ws_ros2/install/warehouse_ros_mongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages",
        "/home/thomas/ws_ros2/install/moveit_msgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages",
        "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages"
    ],
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled"
}
```

But no matter what I do I can't seem to get rid of these squiggles.

[image]

Comment: From this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-includepath intellisense is only picking up system include paths, not IncludePath in the properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing configurationProvider from `c_cpp_properties.json` did the trick and intellisense is working now. [image]

Comment: Does anyone know what `"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"` is even for?

Comment: Apparently it is to break intellisense

Comment: Actually, I believe that was added by a cmake extension I installed.

Answer (score 4):

1. Update the `"includePath": []` configuration in your `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file with the following:

```
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/ros/noetic/include/**",
                "/usr/include/eigen3"
            ],
```

2. Open your `ros workspace` with VScode directly `code my_ros_ws`.
   both work for me

Comment: This is the only one that should be accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

As a reference: I had the same issue but due to a different reason:

Turns out that in my case it was due to having [multiple root folders](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) in my workspace (through RMB and "Add Folder to Workspace...").

By copying the .vscode folder (with `c_cpp_properties.json`) to each of the root folders, it seems to be resolved.