# VS Code underlining #include in cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When i include iostream or string it just underlines it like an error and says:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\...\main.cpp).
cannot open source file "iostream"
cannot open source file "string"
```

I don't know if it's a code error or just VS Code playing with me. Only thing it tells me is to edit the json file.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-includepath

Comment: Often if you can't tell the difference it's time to reconsider the choice of build tools.  Retreat to a simpler tool and return to Visual Studio Code, if you feel the need, when you have a better grip on C++ and can tell when your code should "just work".