# How do I get Visual Studio Code to include non-standard libraries with angle brackets <>?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include-path, vscode-code-runner, arduinojson

I am trying to run a program using the [ArduinoJson](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson) library with the VSC extension [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) but I cannot compile it.

There are no markup errors or warnings in VSC but when I try to run this snippet:

```
#include "../External_Libraries/ArduinoJson/ArduinoJson.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << "Done.\n";
    return 0;}
```

I get the error output below:

```
In file included from ../External_Libraries/ArduinoJson/src/ArduinoJson.hpp:17,\
                 from ../External_Libraries/ArduinoJson/src/ArduinoJson.h:9,\
                 from ../External_Libraries/ArduinoJson/ArduinoJson.h:5,\
                 from localtest.cpp:17:\ ../External_Libraries/ArduinoJson/src/ArduinoJson/Array/ArrayRef.hpp:7:10: fatal error:\ ArduinoJson/Array/ArrayFunctions.hpp: No such file or directory\
#include <ArduinoJson/Array/ArrayFunctions.hpp>\
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\ compilation terminated.
```

Inside the ArduinoJson library, there are some include commands using double quotes and some using angle brackets:

```
#include "src/ArduinoJson.h"
//...   
#include <ArduinoJson/Array/ArrayFunctions.hpp>
```

It appears that only the include statements with angle brackets are a problem. I have tried updating my include paths in settings.json as well as in c_cpp_properties.json to cover this, but it has not worked:

In settings.json:

```
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
    "C:\\...\\project",
    "C:\\...\\project\\External_Libraries\\ArduinoJson\\src",
    "C:\\...\\project\\External_Libraries\\ArduinoJson\\src\\ArduinoJson\\Array"],
"C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe"
```

In c_cpp_properties.json:

```
"name": "Win32",
"includePath":[
    "${default}",
    "C:/.../project",
    "C:/.../project/External_Libraries/ArduinoJson/src/ArduinoJson/Array"],
"defines":[
    "_DEBUG",
    "UNICODE",
    "_UNICODE"],
"cStandard": "gnu17",
"cppStandard": "gnu++14",
"intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86",
"compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
"compilerArgs": ["-I C:\\...\\project\\External_Libraries"]
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

My folder structure is

> project/
> --src/
> ----localtest.cpp
> --External_Libraries/
> ----ArduinoJson/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround: Instead of Code Runner I installed the [Compile Run](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danielpinto8zz6.c-cpp-compile-run) extension and configured it to use g++ instead of gcc with the compiler argument "-I C:/.../project/External_Libraries/ArduinoJson/src" -> and this works!

In settings.json:

```
"c-cpp-compile-run.cpp-compiler": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
"c-cpp-compile-run.cpp-flags": "-Wall -Wextra -Wa,-mbig-obj -I C:/.../project/External_Libraries/ArduinoJson/src",
```

The Code Runner extension seems to be using a different compiler and paths which I have not been able to properly update. Compile Run allows to set specific compiler and paths just for this extension, so that's easier to handle in my opinion.

I would still very much like to know how I can properly update the compiler and include paths for Code Runner.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change last `includePath` to "C:/.../project/External_Libraries/ArduinoJson/src". That is because actual include already has it as relative path `#include <ArduinoJson/Array/ArrayFunctions.hpp>`

```
      "name": "Win32",
  "includePath":[
      "${default}",
      "C:/Users/pohl/Documents/Git/IDEAL_AgentsOnHardware",
      "C:/.../project/External_Libraries/ArduinoJson/src"],
  "defines":[
      "_DEBUG",
      "UNICODE",
      "_UNICODE"],
  "cStandard": "gnu17",
  "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
  "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86",
  "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
  "compilerArgs": ["-I C:\\...\\project\\External_Libraries"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You have a good point but unfortunately it didn't work. I get the same error message. Are there maybe different include paths for different things in VSC? Is there a specific include path for the Code Runner extension for example?

Comment: have you already tried to do same path change for `C_Cpp.default.includePath`? If not, could you try?

Comment: I have tried that, too - but to no avail. I still get the same error message. When I compile this on a Linux machine however, I have a symlink named "ArduinoJson" to the ArduinoJson/src directory in the same directory as localtest.cpp and just use "-I ArduinoJson" to include that - and this works! Unfortunately though, I cannot use symlinks on my Windows machine.

Comment: I looked at https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson. The file ArduinoJson/src/ArduinoJson.hpp does not have that include. Perhaps you have changed source?  Could you check. Also, try replacing \\ with /. Lastly look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-includepath

Comment: The problem arises at line 17 of ArduinoJson.hpp, which includes "ArduinoJson/Array/ArrayRef.hpp" and in ArrayRef.hpp at line 7 we find #include <ArduinoJson/Array/ArrayFunctions.hpp> which causes the problem.

I replaced all \\ but still it doesn't work.

Your linked question gave me an idea though. Instead of "Code Runner" I installed the "Compile Run" extension and configured it to use g++ instead of gcc with the compiler argument "-I C:/.../project/External_Libraries/ArduinoJson/src" -> and this works! The Code Runner extension seems to be using different compiler and paths, I guess.