# How do I get my main file to include the .h fie for a class?

Tags: c++, class, include, header-files

So I just started learning about classes and for some reason, I can't seem to use them in my main file. Every time I run the following code it shows the following error. Please someone help. I am very confused

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zu5i.png)

Comment: Please don't show images of text, least of all code. Copy-paste the code and the full and complete error output into the question *as text*.

Comment: Use `#include "Headers/DataVal.h"`

Comment: Also please tell us the path to both the source and header files. Are they in the same directory, or in different directories?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-include-stdio-h-saying-add-include-path-to-settings) is about adding include paths that aren't part of the project, but you might still find it useful to add say `"{workspaceFolder}/Headers"` to the include paths.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your header file in a directory named `Headers` you need to pass it as whole path

```cpp
#include "Headers/DataVal.h"
```

Comment: IMHO, the include paths or search directories should be passed to the compiler and not placed in the source code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I agree on that