# MPI installation in visual code for windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, mpi

I'm working on a university project where I have to use MPI( Message Passing Interface) for parallel programming. I will be using the language C as a background, and I did all the setup for C in my VS Code and the programs of C worked fine. For MPI I needed to install the msmpisdk wrapper with executable msmpisetup for the setup, I added the path of the bin file in my environment variables C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin, however my VScode doesn't recognize the mpi library in my code showing me this error :   mpi.h: No such file or directory
2 | #include <mpi.h>

I searched for a solution all the day but failed !

Do you have any ideas how I can fix that please ?

I have windows 10

Comment: You must include the path where the mpi.h header file is present in your "Additional Include directories" in Visual Studio, refer this [page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/a-tour-of-cpp-modules-in-visual-studio/#external-modules)

Comment: thank you for answering, but I want to install the mpi in my Vscode and not in visual studio, I did add the path in my environment variables of mpi sdk file but still didn't work! for visual studio it's easy to do it but I dont know if it's possible in vs code because I prefer work on it instead of installing visual studio...

Comment: For VS Code, you can modify the include path such that it includes the path where the mpi header files are present. You need to edit the file c_cpp_properties.json, and the `C_Cpp.default.includePath` element.

Comment: Refer more details on configuring that `includePath` in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58839719/14973743)

Comment: were you able to configure the include path in VS code and compile?

Comment: Heey @AnandSowmithiran Thank you for the answer, i moved to visual studio instead of VScode but i will try the solution you gave me and let you know if it works (y)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS C[image]ode, you just need to add a simple line to **c_cpp_properties.json**. This file can be found under the **.vscode** folder in your project root directory. Under configurations edit includePath to have:

```
"includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/MPI/Include"
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem to setup MSMPI in windows. After spending 5/7 hours, finally I could build and run mpi program in c.

### **The MPI installetion processes are--**

1. You need to **install a compiler according to your computer Bit
   architecture.** As example, If you have 64 bit windows pc, then you
   could download mingw-w64 compiler.To download 64 bit mingw, go to
   this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/) and download this like the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jMGy.png).
2. after extracting the compiler and setting environment variable. Run a simple hellow world program in c.
3. Then download msmpi software from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=105289) and install.
4. you need to install first *.exe* file then *.msi* **in a folder which all name must not contain any space.**
   **As Example-** Folder name **Parallel Processing** is not permissible. you need to write **Parallel_processing**
5. Then download a sample mpi code,  If you get `cannot open source file "mpi.h"C/C++(1696)`. Then go to `Quick fix` option and click `edit "includepath" settings`. then edit like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSIHk.png).
6. then you need to open `task.json` file located in `.vscode` folder. you could press `F1`, search task and go to `task: Configure task`. then click `c/c++` option.
7. after opening task.json, you need to write

> ```
>             "-I",
>           "${MSMPI_INC}",
>           "-L",
>           "${MSMPI_LIB64}",
>           "-lmsmpi",
> ```

like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbkjV.png).

8. Now you could build your mpi program, go to terminal and click `Run build task`. It will show build successfully and make a `.exe` file.
9. Now you could run `.exe` file with `mpiexec -n <no_of_Threads> <exe file name>` command.