# VSCode (Windows 10) c++ intelliSense errors of include path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am currently working with an open source c++ project and have a weird intelliSense error. I have the following two *.cpp files in the same folder, and as can be seen in the image. the intellisense works in one file but not in the other.

[image]

c_cpp_properties.json is as follows:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/src/**",
            "${workspaceFolder}/utils/**",
            "C:/libs/install/opencv-3.4.16/include",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/aruco/include/aruco"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
        "compilerPath": "cl.exe",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64",
        "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

So I am sure the include paths are correct because it shows them correctly in the left file, and the projects gets compiled too. Does anyone know any tricks I can get it to show them correctly in the other file? I don't really want to disable error squiggles entirely either.

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` has nothing to do with compiling the program

Comment: Question is not about compiling.

Comment: It has come to my attetion that this display error of include path only comes in the main.cpp, so it maybe related to that. independent of this, I have had some weird behaviour with the IntelliSense. So I'll leave this question here for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that, as noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-include-stdio-h-saying-add-include-path-to-settings) thread, IntelliSense will grab headers based around the path from `compilerPath` if this option is present in the `c_cpp_properties.json`.

From some personal testing with a similar issue involving Qt includes, this issue may be fixed by simply leaving out `compilerPath` entirely, as it is an optional field and forces IntelliSense to search the paths included in `includePath`. After this, I was able to re-add the `compilerPath`, so it's possible this is just a quirk with the way IntelliSense builds its database.