# VSCode C++ can't find header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include-path

VSCode:1.65.2
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

When I try to compile my C++ code in VSCode terminal or system terminal, I get an error message saying

```
fatal error: 'itensor/all.h' file not found
```

Then, I updated include path settings in VSCode to add paths to required header files because I get squiggles under header files saying

```
include errors detected, update include path settings.
```

Yet, my build task fails and header files are not being read.

Kindly help.

I referred some previous answers, but they don't seem to work for me at all.

Comment: why do other answers not work? What did you try?

Comment: I updated all the include path settings as directed and I still face the same issue. I tried this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-include-stdio-h-saying-add-include-path-to-settings)