# VS Code doesn't recognize Pi Pico SDK headers

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi-pico

So I have everything setup to compile in Windows Subsystem for Linux and that is all working fine. I'm writing my code in VS Code and it doesn't recognize the headers such as "pico/stdlib.h". The code compiles and works fine but it would be nice to get Code setup properly so I get the auto-fill features and such.

How do I properly link the SDK libs with VS Code?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to set up VS code for your build environment via some JSON nonsense: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522462/visual-studio-code-include-stdio-h-saying-add-include-path-to-settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I experienced this same issue.

Edit the include path by hovering over the red underlined `#include` lines, click `Quick fix...`, and click the edit `includePath` option.

[image]

Scroll down to the `Include path` section and add `${env:PICO_SDK_PATH}/**`. Make sure the setting saves properly. This adds the SDK directory by the `PICO_SDK_PATH` environment variable which contains the headers and associated files.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome! I started using Atom since I switched to Linux but this will probably help others.

Comment: For some reason, this wouldn't work for me. I had to type out the absolute path with an additional /** on the end `<stuff>/pico-sdk/**`. I must not have that environment variable set correctly. I tried opening the VS terminal and providing an absolute path to the pico-sdk (`setx PICO_SDK_PATH /path/to/pico-sdk`), but it still won't work.

Comment: @GabeMorris - check if your distribution uses a specific file for the gcc-cross compiler, e.g. `/etc/profile.d/gcc-cross.sh` and put the environment variables there. Otherwise, just put them in your `~/.bashrc`. You will need two-lines for each variable you want to set/export (you can do it in 1, but..), the expanded way is, e.g. `PICO_SDK_PATH="/path/to/pico-sdk"` and then `export PICO_SDK_PATH`. Also, enter the same at the command line for the current shell, or restart the shell so it pull the new settings in. Now this answer will work.