# cannot open source file stdio.h C in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, header-files

I've been trying to learn C recently.
When I execute the following code in visual studio code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{  
    // variable declaration
    int a, b, c;

    // user prompts
    printf("enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("enter another number\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    // operation
    c = a + b;
    // printing
    printf("your number is %d", c);

    return 0;
}
```

it works fine. But I am given this error:

```
cannot open source file "stdio.h"
```

I have properly installed gcc, msys, etc. yet any and all `#include` header lines give the same error.
Here is a image of the error (indent rainbow, material theme, C/C++ and error lens extensions):
[image: error image link]

Comment: Not a duplicate question but it might be the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37522462/583044

Comment: *it works fine. but I am given this error:* - it can't "work fine" if it is really can't open the file. Please show the whole compiler output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "It Works fine" I'm assuming that it compiles, If you have installed **C/C++ Extensions** Pack for VSCode it might need to configure the Include path

Please, take a look at configuration [Example](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference)