# Why does VS Code's C/C++ extension IntelliSense "forget" default system include paths when I define other include paths?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

To be clear, I want to **add** another include path, not completely override the default include paths.

I'm aware of the c_cpp_properties.json `configurations.includePath` property, but that appears to be a complete override of the include paths.

Sure, I could figure out what the full list of include paths is, but that seems like a bunch of per-configuration work and an ongoing maintenance headache. I want something like configurations/additionalIncludePath that just adds to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `includePath` states ([link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference)):

> If on Windows with Visual Studio installed, or if a compiler is specified in the compilerPath setting, it is not necessary to list the system include paths in this list

And quoting the documentation for `compilerPath`:

> The extension will query the compiler to determine the system include paths and default defines to use for IntelliSense.
>
> Putting `"compilerPath": ""` (empty string) will skip querying a compiler. This is useful if a specified compiler doesn't support the arguments that are used for the query, as the extension will default back to any compiler it can find (like Visual C). Leaving out the `compilerPath` property does not skip the query.

So if I am understanding that right, either you have set `compilerPath` to an empty string, or you are on Windows and not using Visual Studio, in which case you will either need to meet those requirements, or specify the system include paths manually in `includePath`.

Note also that you can specify system include paths as a setting, `C_Cpp.default.systemIncludePath`, with related docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp#_system-includes) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp#_system-include-pathdefines-resolution-strategies).

Comment: I'm on macOS. Adding compilerPath to c_cpp_properties.json fixed the problem. I used the extension UI to generate this originally. Apparently by default it leaves this blank. I would have expected it to fall through to the default configuration compilerPath but apparently not.